# Watir Chrome Driver "EOFError: end of file reached" Error

Tags: selenium, debian, watir, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running:

Chrome Version google-chrome-stable/unknown uptodate 27.0.1453.93-r200836

Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 (squeeze) 32x

When I try to run:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'
headless = Headless.new
headless.start
b = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
```

I get:

```
EOFError: end of file reached
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `read_nonblock'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `rbuf_fill'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2563:in `read_status_line'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2552:in `read_new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1320:in `block in transport_request'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1317:in `catch'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1317:in `transport_request'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1294:in `request'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1287:in `block in request'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:746:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:629:in `raw_execute'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:98:in `create_session'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:29:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `for'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from (irb):7:in `new'
        from (irb):7
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I'm really not sure how to even start troubleshooting this. I'm searching google but not finding any fix that works for me so far. Hopefully someone can help with this.

Comment: You can start by sharing your operating system and version.

Comment: Chrome Version google-chrome-stable/unknown uptodate 27.0.1453.93-r200836, Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 (squeeze) 32x

Comment: newUserNameHere: Do you have the chromedriver in your PATH?

Comment: Just checked, I sure do. It also starts up just fine:

root@servername:~# chromedriver
Started ChromeDriver
port=9515
version=26.0.1383.0
log=/root/chromedriver.log

Comment: Also I get the same thing when I start up headless chrome using selenium. So I know it's not specific to watir. Before the error message appears it seems like it's processing the last command for about 20 seconds or so, whereas if I just start up chromedriver it's almost instant.

Comment: Check if you have xvfb installed/enabled and configured.

Comment: I do have xvfb installed and working. I can virtualize firefox with it just fine, just keep getting this error for chrome.

Comment: From what I've seen this type of exception seems related to using `HTTPS` with (`Net::HTTP`)[http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html]. Does this help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've come back to this a few months later. It seems that whatever this originally caused this was fixed when I downloaded the latest chromedriver available here:

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Currently that is version 2.9

Comment: If you have multiple chromedriver files on your system, then "which chromedriver" and "chromedriver --version" might be pointing to a different chromedriver than what Selenium sees.  Do a find command to locate all files named "chromedriver" and remove them before placing the most recent version from the link above in your /usr/local/bin and it should work